# Inline code with too much whitespace inside quotes escapes its container

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Here's an example:

> `int main(void) { puts("This is just a test to demonstrate
>                            the issue                                                                 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla`

And here's a screenshot of how the above is rendered:

[image: example]

I can reproduce this on the main site as well:

[image: main site]

I originally discovered this on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389394/3889449) of mine:

[image: second example]

In this second case, there doesn't even seem to be that much whitespace.

Comment: No repro in FF 69.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Unless you are writing comments, this can be totally avoided by using proper code blocks.

Comment: No repro in chrome (76) on Mac (10.4 mojave) and safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been silently taken care of:

[image: screenshot]

Long inline code blocks now break on whitespace inside quotes.